# Compose hierarchy of UI actions based on class type of state passed in

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a composable view that show a view for different types of objects.

```
@Composable
fun Details(
   liveData: LiveData<State>,
   onAction: ((Action) -> Unit)? = null
) {
   val state = liveData.observeAsState()
   when (state.value) {
      is AuthorState -> {
         AuthorDetails(state, onAction)
      }
      is BookState -> {
         BookDetails(state, onAction)
      } else -> {
         DefaultState(state, onAction)
      }
   }
}


sealed class Action<T> {
   class Name<T>(val id: T): Action<T>()
}

sealed class AuthorAction {
   class Name(val id: Long): Action<Long>()
   class Address(val author: AuthorState): AuthorAction()
}

@Composable
fun AuthorDetails(
   authorState: AuthorState,
   onAction: (AuthorAction) -> Unit
) {
   ...
   onAction(AuthorAction.Address(authorState))
   ...
}

sealed class BookAction {
   class Name(val id: String): Action<String>()
   class Location(val book: BookState): BookAction()
}

@Composable
fun BookDetails(
   bookState: BookState,
   onAction: (BookAction) -> Unit
) {
   ...
   onAction(BookAction.Location(bookState))
   ...
}
```

And in Activity:

```
view.bottom_sheet.setContent {
   Details(viewModel.details) { action ->
      when(action) {
         is BookAction -> onBookAction(action)
         is AuthorAction -> onAuthorAction(action)
         is DefaultAction -> onDefaultAction(action)
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to define a hierarchy of actions that are based on the state that is passed to the composable.

Problem is the "Details" composable expects an "Action" type, not BookAction or AuthorAction.  I have played around with the inheritance, however usually end up with a lot of duplication.

**Edit:** Using @broot answer, having issues invoking action from composable:

Adding back in "id" template:

```
sealed interface Action<I>
sealed interface AuthorAction<I> : Action<I>
sealed interface BookAction<I> : Action<I>

class Name<I>(val id: I) : Action<I>, AuthorAction<I>, BookAction<I>
class Address(val author: AuthorState) : AuthorAction<Long>
class Location(val book: BookState) : BookAction<String>

interface State<I, out A : Action>
interface BookState : State<String, BookAction>
interface AuthorState : State<Long, AuthorAction>
interface DefaultState<I> : State<I, Action>

fun <I, A : Action<I> Details(
    liveData: LiveData<State<I, A>>,
    onAction: ((A) -> Unit)? = null
) {
   onAction?.invoke(Name("id"))
}
```

Doing this gives me a compile error:

```
Type mismatch. 
Required: A
Found: Action<I>
```

I can change the "Details" function:

```
fun <I, A : Action> Details(
    liveData: LiveData<State<I, A>>,
    onAction: ((A: Action<I>) -> Unit)? = null
) {
   onAction?.invoke(Name("id"))
}
```

However when I do this, action is always "Action" in client calling code, not BookAction or AuthorAction.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like SpecificAction to have all of generic classes actions, ie Click and Drag as well". How is SpecificAction.Click different than GeneralAction.Click in your use cases? Did you just want Specific, Click and Drag all to have the same base class, for example Action? If so, keep in mind that sealed classes can extend other sealed classes and you can "nest" sealed classes (if you want to get namespaces such as Action.Specific.MySpecificAction).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems two solve here.

First is how to structure actions, so they are sealed, but at the same time an action could belong to multiple groups of actions. For example, `Name` action is a part of `AuthorAction`, `BookAction` and also base `Action` group.

We can do this by replacing sealed classes with sealed interfaces and inheriting from multiple of them. For example:

```kotlin
sealed interface Action
sealed interface AuthorAction : Action
sealed interface BookAction : Action

class Name(val id: String) : Action, AuthorAction, BookAction
class Address(val author: AuthorState) : AuthorAction
class Location(val book: BookState) : BookAction
```

(I intentionally removed `T` from `Name` and `Action` just to simplify the code and focus on what's important.)

Second problem is how to choose a proper group of actions depending on the type of state object. We can do this by parameterizing state with its related action:

```kotlin
interface State<out A : Action>
interface BookState : State<BookAction>
interface AuthorState : State<AuthorAction>
interface DefaultState : State<Action>
```

We also have to parameterize the `Details()` function:

```kotlin
fun <A : Action> Details(
    liveData: LiveData<State<A>>,
    onAction: ((A) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    when (val state = liveData.observeAsState().value) {
        is AuthorState -> {
            onAction?.invoke(Name("foo") as A)
            onAction?.invoke(Address(state) as A)

            // or:
            
            AuthorDetails(state, onAction as ((AuthorAction) -> Unit)?)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like this:

```kotlin
val authorState: LiveData<AuthorState> = TODO()
Details(authorState) { action -> // action is AuthorAction
    when (action) { // when is exhaustive
        is Name -> TODO()
        is Address -> TODO()
    }
}

val bookState: LiveData<BookState> = TODO()
Details(bookState) { action -> // action is BookAction
    when (action) { // when is exhaustive
        is Name -> TODO()
        is Location -> TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what do you try to achieve with this `GenericDetails()` function. Could you update the question with an explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need, but sealed classes/interfaces can still extend other interfaces. You can create `Action` interface, extend all other interfaces from it and use it as a parameter type in `GenericDetails()`. You can make this `Action` interface sealed if this is what you need. You can also e.g. make `SpecificAction` extend `GenericAction`, however, this is more tricky as it would make harder to perform exhaustive `when` on `GenericAction`.

Comment: I updated the answer to proved a more concrete example of what I am trying to accomplish if that helps.

Comment: Before answering I need to confirm two things: 1. You have your own interface/class named 'State' and e.g. 'BookState' is its subtype. 2. There is a bug in your code, it should be 'when (state.value) { ... }'. I ask these questions, because I don't see how your code code work. I think 'observeAsState()' will never return one of your state objects.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  State is my generic UI state.  Its a data class, BookState and AuthorState inherit from that.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to re-read its as a whole. Also, I think I was wrong about this `state.value`. I missed that you used `by`, not `=`.

Comment: thanks! However I am still running into an issue invoking the action from the composable, see update.  Seems that adding in template you removed is causing issues.

Comment: You just have to cast action to `A` (or cast `onAction`). It is unchecked cast, but should be safe to do. And it is unrelated to `I`. See my update.

Comment: Regarding `I`, I'm not sure what's its purpose as most of actions does not use it in any way, so it seems like it shouldn't be declared for all actions. It complicates things quite a lot and I have a feeling you will have another question on "how to do it with `I`". Also, I'm not sure if it was just a simple mistake, but in your example `AuthorState` is related to `String`, but `Address` which is one of actions of `AuthorState` is of type `Long`. This is inconsistent and won't work.

Comment: Yes AuthorState was a mistake, updated.  "I" is used as the ID type of the state.  This is used in the viewmodel to query for the entity from the database.  The current view only holds a "view" state which include just the data needed for the view, plus the ID so it can be looked up later.  Unchecked cast exceptions are what I was trying to avoid with my approach.  At this point it seems this has become overly complicated and harder to maintain.  Seems duplicating the like Actions for Author and Book is a better approach.  I truly appreciate your help and effort!